# Главное и единственное расширение в создаваемом сайте index.php

Tags: php, html

Создаю в Dreamweaver сразу с раширением php,чем это грозит. Короче - нет ни одного файла с расширением html.

Answer (score 2):

Тем что на хостинге без php работать не будет.
Хотя если вы не используете php, то хранить чистый html код внутри *.php файлов глупо!

Answer (score 0):

Вообще, любой адекватный хостер на нормальном тарифе "держит" php. У меня в проектах файлов с чистым html почти никогда нет. Всё на шаблонизаторах.